# Edit Control Is Behaving The Way It Shouldn't Be

Tags: c++, mfc, editcontrol, omniorb

At first, I made a Corba C++ Server in Win32 Console Application following this [guide](http://www.mario-konrad.ch/wiki/doku.php?id=programming%3acorba%3aconnect_orbs#Links), and its working. From that code, I made a Corba Server in MFC.

From the C++ Win32 Server I have this code:

```
cout << argv[0] << ": server 'TestServer' bound" << endl;
```

And here the output:

```
C:\Users\innistrad\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestServer\
Debug\TestServer.exe: server 'TestServer' bound
```

The content of the argv[0] is this:

```
C:\Users\innistrad\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestServer\
Debug\TestServer.exe
```

So, in MFC, I made it like this:

```
msg = ": server 'TestServer' bound";
mDisp.SetWindowText(__argv[0] + msg);
```

Problem is, it's not displaying the values in the parenthesis.

But, when I do this

```
AfxMessageBox(__argv[0] + msg);
```

I am getting the output same as aforementioned.

I have tried to change the edit control to a new edit control and to a list box but to no avail. What seems to be the problem? Can anybody help?

Thanks.

Comment: We can only guess. What's `argv` and `__argv` and how do they relate? What's the type of `msg` and `mDisp`. And why the parentheses around the string literal when assigning it to `msg`? You really need to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). When you say the you are getting the values, how did you verify this?

Comment: sorry, ill be editing the question and post the output also.. Thanks @IInspectable

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of variable `msg` Try the following

```
CString msgStr = ": server 'TestServer' bound";
mDisp.SetWindowText(CString(__argv[0]) + msgStr);
```

Comment: Thank you @N3Xg3N for the help. The msg is CString, I declared it at the .h file and I also tried doing what you have shown but I still don't get the desired output. Again, Thank you.

Comment: Try this `CString msgStr(_T(": server 'TestServer' bound"));`

Comment: @ N3Xg3N, thank you.
I had it fixed already.
UpdateWindow() did the trick.